# How to exit this TicTacToe Game loop?

Tags: c++

I am trying to make a TicTacToe Game, but something isn't working in my code.  I made a new class called `TicTacToeGame` and I have my `source.cpp` (main file). Everything  was fine until I made a loop to test if a space is occupied.

Since then, it asks me to enter a coordinate for X. I give it an answer and then it asks me for a Y coordinate.  I give it an answer; but, again it asks for a Y coordinate, and if I give him a bad input it start spamming me with that question or tells me that I've introduced a bad input.

What can I do?  I want to know what's wrong.

### `TicTacToeGame.h`

```
 #pragma once
    class TicTacToeGame
    {
    public:
    TicTacToeGame();

    void playGame();

    private:

    bool placeMarker(int x, int y, char currentPlayer);
    int getXCoord();
    int getYCoord();

    char board[3][3];

    // Clears the board
    void clearBoard();
    // Prints the board
    void printBoard();
    };
```

### `TicTacToe.cpp`

```
    #include "TicTacToeGame.h"
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    TicTacToeGame::TicTacToeGame()
    {
        clearBoard();
    };

    void TicTacToeGame::playGame()
    {
       char player1 = 'X';
       char player2 = 'Y';

    char currentPlayer = 'X';
    bool isDone = false;

    int x, y;

    while (isDone == false) {

        printBoard();

        x = getXCoord();
        y = getYCoord();

        if (placeMarker(x, y, currentPlayer) == false) {
            cout << "That spot is occupied\n";
        }
        else
        {
            // Switch player so every player can put markers
            if (currentPlayer == player1) {
                currentPlayer = player2;
            }
            else
            {
                currentPlayer = player1;
            }
        }
    }
}



int TicTacToeGame::getXCoord()
{
    bool isInputBad = true;
    int x;

    while (isInputBad == true) {
        cout << "Enter the X coordinate: ";
        cin >> x;

        if (x < 1 || x > 3) {
            cout << "Invalid coordinate!\n";
        }
        else
        {
            isInputBad = false;
        }
    }
    return x - 1;
}

int TicTacToeGame::getYCoord()
{
    bool isInputBad = true;
    int y;

    while (isInputBad == true) {
        cout << "Enter the Y coordinate: ";
        cin >> y;
    }

    if (y < 1 || y > 3) {
        cout << "Invalid coordinate!\n";
    }
    else
    {
        isInputBad = false;
    }
    return y - 1;
}

bool TicTacToeGame::placeMarker(int x, int y, char currentPlayer)
{
    if (board[y][x] != ' ') {
        return false;
    }

    board[y][x] = currentPlayer;
    return true;
}

void TicTacToeGame::clearBoard()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
            board[i][j] = ' ';
        }
    }
}

void TicTacToeGame::printBoard()
{
    cout << endl;
    cout << " |1 2 3|\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
        cout << "--------\n";
        cout << i+1 << "|" << board[i][0] << "|" << board[i][1] << "|" << board[i][2] << "|\n";
    }
    cout << "--------\n";
}
```

### `source.cpp`

```
#include "TicTacToeGame.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    TicTacToeGame game;

    game.playGame();

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: None of your logic for checking whether the y co-ordinate is bad, is within the loop where you keep asking for input (i.e. check your brackets match correctly). I'm voting to close as this is a typographical error and has no use for future readers.

Comment: This is a perfect time for you to learn to use the debugger to step through the code as it executes. It's also the perfect time to learn to properly indent your code so you can more clearly see the flow of execution. If you'd done that in the first place, the problem would jump right out at you.

Comment: please i dont know whats working wrong. Please just give me an answer... i need help OK?? i am a beginner in C++ . Please help me

Comment: We've told you what's wrong. Read what we wrote. Do your own homework.

Comment: oh ok then ... i will try and i ll be back with an answer , thx...

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I will try to keep in mind that i have to be MORE careful with these loops! Thanks again. I have just thought it can be something worse! Thanks again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your while loop will never exit,

The X Coord While Loop:

```
 while (isInputBad == true) {
        cout << "Enter the X coordinate: ";
        cin >> x;

        if (x < 1 || x > 3) {
            cout << "Invalid coordinate!\n";
        }
        else
        {
            isInputBad = false;
        }
    } // end of while loop
```

The Y Coord While loop:

```
while (isInputBad == true) {
        cout << "Enter the Y coordinate: ";
        cin >> y;
    } // end of while loop

    if (y < 1 || y > 3) {
        cout << "Invalid coordinate!\n";
    }
    else
    {
        isInputBad = false;
    }
```

See how the validation code is outside of the while loop for the Y Coord?
The while condition `isInputBad` will always equal true because it would get set to false after the loop.

Move the end of the while loop after the if statement and it should work.

Comment: oh... Thanks a lot for your answer i will try to keep in mind that i have to be more careful with these loops. I cant believe I have actually missed that. I thought it was something worse. Thanks!